# Crop foreground of image in Python

Tags: python, image-processing

I have manipulated a jpg image so that I have foreground isolated, and all black pixels everywhere else.
I'd like to be able to crop the image so that there are no full black rows above and below, or full black columns left and right of the foreground.
I'm thinking I could get the 4 indices I need just looping through the Numpy array, but was wondering if there is a more straightforward and/or fast approach.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


im=np.array(    
[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,1,1,0,0],    
[0,1,1,1,0,0,0],    
[0,0,1,1,0,0,0],    
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])

plt.imshow(im, cmap=plt.cm.gray,interpolation='nearest')
```

[image]

Then **something happens here** and I get:

[image]

Comment: There's nothing wrong with looping over all the pixels. You're only doing it once from each direction and stopping as soon as you find something, so it should go pretty quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`im[~np.all(im == 0, axis=1)]` can remove the rows with all zero. `axis=2` will be the columns deletion. Would that work for you?